# Apache mod-pagespeed installation affects mod-spdy?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, page-speed, mod-pagespeed, spdy

Recently my site (an https connection, running on an Amazon EC2 ubuntu apache2.2) has this issue where I need to load the page several times (3-4) before it will load normally without issue. It will then load normally as long as I keep loading pages regularly (every couple seconds). It will stall again if I don't load pages for a few minutes.

It has nothing to do with my application because I don't have this problem with the exact same app codebase on my Apache installation on my laptop.

The only things to my knowledge that I've changed is that I recently installed mod_spdy and then a few weeks later I installed mod_pagespeed, https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/mod. However, I have since turned mod_pagespeed off by setting its pagespeed.conf to `mod_pagespeed off`. Unfortunately, that didn't solve the problem.

The line below is how every of last 10 lines of my error.log look:

```
# tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
...
[32728:32729:ERROR:mod_spdy.cc(162)] request->chunked == 1 in request GET / HTTP/1.1
[Sat Jun 02 04:50:08 2012] [warn] [client 50.136.93.153] [stream 5]   
[32728:32729:WARNING:http_to_spdy_filter.cc(113)] HttpToSpdyFilter is not the last filter 
in the chain: chunk
```

any thoughts?
thank you,
tim

Comment: Perhaps an obvious comment but, what do those error.logs tell you? Open them up in your editor and check, or `tail -f nameoffile` and hit reload on the page and see what appears.

Comment: @igrigorik the error message above is the one I get when I unsuccessfully refresh the page so mod_spdy appears to be my problem. I'm just not sure what to do about that. Suggestions?

Comment: Oh. So that has nothing to do with mod_pagespeed.. instead, it looks like its your mod_spdy module. Check these links: http://code.google.com/p/mod-spdy/issues/detail?id=39, https://developers.google.com/speed/spdy/mod_spdy/php

Comment: @igrigorik thanks for the links. It looks like to get mod_spdy to work i have to "disable mod_php as part of making the switch to mod_fcgid". That sounds scary. I'm worried about unforseen issues that will come with the mod_php->mod_fcgid switch. Do you know of any? Yes, my website is running PHP.

Comment: No, sorry don't have any hands on experience with either of those.